# "Connecting string cannot be empty" error when initiating CDbConnection

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii, connection

I tried this to create a database connection but it didn't go well ,

```
try
    {
        $connection=new CDbConnection();
        $connection->active=true;
        $transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo($e);
    }
```

i got an error:-

```
connecting string cannot be empty
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not configuring the db connection via an application component?

Comment: @DaSourcerer Not only _any_, but rather there can be _plenty_ reasons for doing so. One of most obvious is to temporarily use another database. You don't want to include another DB connection in your application's configuration, if you're using it only for a single, simple, one action-like operation, right?

Comment: @trejder I'm not sure if that argument holds true: Application components aren't loaded until needed, so there shouldn't be any overhead involved. OTOH, condiguring a component here will minimize code duplication if that connection is needed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Yii Guide on DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao):

> To establish a database connection, create a CDbConnection instance and activate it. A data source name (DSN) is needed to specify the information required to connect to the database. A username and password may also be needed to establish the connection.
>
> An exception will be raised in case an error occurs during establishing the connection (e.g. bad DSN or invalid username/password).

```
$connection=new CDbConnection($dsn,$username,$password);
// establish connection. You may try...catch possible exceptions
$connection->active=true;
......
$connection->active=false;  // close connection
```

You passed nothing for $dsn so it throw the exception:

`CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.'));`